# Generate five random Colors without making 15 randomized variables

Tags: java, random, colors

I'm creating a very beginner Java program that creates five Panels of random color and random size (each panel smaller than the next).

The problem:

While my program works, I've had to type a new variable for *everything*. For the five panels with 3 colors each (R,G,B) I've had to create 15 variables. Isn't there a way to call upon random within the (R,G,B) rather than creating so many variables?

Here is an excerpt of my code that deals with how the color is randomized in each panel:

```
//Random Color Maker 1
Random rand = new Random();
int a = rand.nextInt(255);
int b = rand.nextInt(255);
int c = rand.nextInt(255);
    int d = rand.nextInt(255);
    int e = rand.nextInt(255);
    int f = rand.nextInt(255);
        int g = rand.nextInt(255);
        int h = rand.nextInt(255);
        int i = rand.nextInt(255);
            int j = rand.nextInt(255);
            int k = rand.nextInt(255);
            int l = rand.nextInt(255);
                int m = rand.nextInt(255);
                int n = rand.nextInt(255);
                int o = rand.nextInt(255);
Color color1 = new Color(a, b, c);
    Color color2 = new Color(d, e, f);
        Color color3 = new Color(g, h, i);
            Color color4 = new Color(j, k, l);
                Color color5 = new Color(m, n, o);

//Panel 1
JPanel Panel1 = new JPanel ();
Panel1.setBackground (color1);
Panel1.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (rand1));
JLabel label1 = new JLabel ("1");
Panel1.add(label1);

//Panel 2        
JPanel Panel2 = new JPanel ();
Panel2.setBackground (color2);
Panel2.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (rand2));
JLabel label2 = new JLabel ("2");
Panel2.add(label2);
Panel2.add(Panel1);
```

Comment: Please, please look into [`loops`](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_for_loops.html)

Comment: Are you _repeating_ anything? What language construct helps us repeat?

Comment: At least that's pretty understandable indenting.

Comment: Congratulations, you have just found the importance of **loop** and **function** -- two very important concepts in programming.

Comment: Also note that when you have names like `Panel1`, `Panel2`, etc., that arrays are strongly indicated.

Comment: Great thanks so much for some of your help! They haven't taught us loops yet so I've been refraining from using that kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

You can introduce a method

```
Random rand = new Random();

private Color randomColor() {
  return new Color(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255));
}

public void yourMethod() {
  //Panel 1
  JPanel Panel1 = new JPanel ();
  Panel1.setBackground (randomColor());
  // ...
}
```

Comment: A few notes about formatting: 1. Don't capitalize `Panel1`. 2. Indent four spaces. 3. Don't put a space between the method name and its arguments.

Comment: You are right, copy-pasted the two lines from original code.

Comment: Thanks for this. They didn't teach us any of this, so I'm surprised they expect us to do a problem like this with multiple panes.

Answer (score -1):

Another thing to consider is using an array to store all of these colors.  One implementation would be as follows (using Udo's randomColor() method):

```
int[] myArray = new int[15];

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    int[i] = randomColor();
}
```

Also, I think you want to do:

`rand.nextInt(256)`, since `nextInt(number)` gives you a random integer between 0 (inclusive) and number (exclusive).  So to make sure 255 is a possible value, you'd have to do 255 + 1 = 256.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that range starts with 0.